# How to find bottleneck on postgres sql join

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a postgres db (9.3.3) table with 60k records of restaurants with each having an address.

In order to see every restaurant with address I join like this:

```
Select name,city 
from accommodations 
  inner join addresses on addresses.accommodations_id = accommodations.id
```

I always thought this wold be the easiest and fastest join possible, but it just doesn't stop running. 
So what's wrong here and what to search for. Thanks in advance.

```
\d
List of relations
Schema  |        Name         |   Type   |  
----------+---------------------+----------
public   | cities              | table    | 
public   | cities_id_seq       | sequence | 
public   | geography_columns   | view     | 
public   | geometry_columns    | view     | 
public   | locations_id_seq    | sequence | 
public   | raster_columns      | view     | 
public   | raster_overviews    | view     |
public   | schema_migrations   | table    | 

public   | spatial_ref_sys     | table    | 
topology | layer               | table    | 
topology | topology            | table    | 
topology | topology_id_seq     | sequence | 
(17 rows)


"public.accommodations";"8232 kB"
"public.addresses";"19 MB"


"Merge Left Join  (cost=0.75..6748.33 rows=68647 width=674) (actual time=0.022..102.891 rows=66249 loops=1)"
"  Merge Cond: (accommodations.id = addresses.accommodation_id)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=9167"
"  ->  Index Scan using accommodations_pkey on accommodations  (cost=0.29..2377.71 rows=68647 width=560) (actual time=0.010..17.053 rows=66249 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1681"
"  ->  Index Scan using idx_addresses_accommodation_id on addresses  (cost=0.29..3370.89 rows=66250 width=114) (actual time=0.008..19.648 rows=66250 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=7486"
"Total runtime: 108.642 ms"
```

Comment: do you have indexes on the tables...?

Comment: I suppose you have indexes on address.restaurant_id and restaurant.id?

Comment: I have an index on restaurants.id but not on the addresses.restaurants_id ? How can I re-index that column?

Comment: Can you please run this and post the results?  It will help us optimize your table.  `explain Select name,city from restaurant inner join address on address.restaurant_id = restaurant.id`

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=postgresql+add+index

Comment: First, you have to give the data structure of your `address` and `restaurant` tables, it would be easier to understand the things...

Comment: CREATE INDEX rest_id_idx ON address (restauraunt_id);

Comment: Ok I created the index. I used another table now called accommodations which has the same relation as mentioned. `"Merge Left Join  (cost=0.75..6748.33 rows=68647 width=674)"
"  Merge Cond: (accommodations.id = addresses.accommodation_id)"
"  ->  Index Scan using accommodations_pkey on accommodations  (cost=0.29..2377.71 rows=68647 width=560)"
"  ->  Index Scan using idx_addresses_accommodation_id on addresses  (cost=0.29..3370.89 rows=66250 width=114)" `. The query runs 23574ms

Comment: @Mark does the explain output shows something unusual?

Comment: Please, provide the following: (1) definitions of your tables as reported by `\d` command of `psql` tool, (2) size (in MB and records) of your tables and (3) `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` of your original query on the tables in subject.

Comment: @vyegorov Please find my edited question above with the informations you requested.Sorry for the missing informations. I just notice how much I forgot since I relied on db orm tools in the past so that I did not use sql for a while

Comment: rows=66249 and that in Total runtime: 108.642 ms, not that bad. Another query might be 10 times faster, but that would not make a big difference, just 90 milliseconds. "The query runs 23574ms", where do you get this information from? That might be the time needed to receive the data that has been found by the database.

Comment: @FrankHeikens That confuses me why does it say runtime 108ms while I have to wait in pgadmin for 23574 ms in order to see the table?

Comment: It takes 108ms to execute the query, but it takes an additional 23466ms to get the data from the database to the client that asked for this data. If you want to improve overall performance, you have to focus on the connection, the netwerk and the client to see where you can make improvements. The good news is that the query is fine.

Comment: ok, I see. So I guess there is nothing I can do about it since I am running on localhost

Comment: None of this makes any sense. Your question is incomplete and contradictory. If you "run on localhost" (no remote server involved) there is no sane way to lose over 20 sec in the data transfer and display. Are you using a prehistoric version of pgAdmin? Try the query in psql for comparison. There might be something wrong with your db.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I just noticed that the query is fast as expected in the console. So it must be related to pgadmin for some reason. Why is the question inappropriate?

Answer (score -1):

If it literally won't stop running, you might want to check if there's some hanged-up session using that table.

We had an issue like that when using Python's `psycopg2`. Once there's a query execution fail next query (no matter the source of the query) to the table would never return a result. Restarting `postgres` service would solve it and adding `rollback` clause on query failure in Python would prevent this from happening again.

Comment: That's what I did now but still it runs 30s even with the index added on the foreign key column